Thread 1: signal SIGABRT with SFML
I am trying to use SFML in Xcode, but as I was trying to run the default code that you get when making a project, I got an error:

Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

This occurred in 0 __abort__with_payload
In case you want the details of the file:
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x18c5ec734 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209               ; =521 
    0x18c5ec738 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x18c5ec73c <+8>:  b.lo   0x18c5ec75c               ; <+40>
    0x18c5ec740 <+12>: pacibsp 
    0x18c5ec744 <+16>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x18c5ec748 <+20>: mov    x29, sp
    0x18c5ec74c <+24>: bl     0x18c584e60               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x18c5ec750 <+28>: mov    sp, x29
    0x18c5ec754 <+32>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x18c5ec758 <+36>: retab  
    0x18c5ec75c <+40>: ret    

I got the error on like 4, which also has the arrow pointing to it.
Also, a tutorial that I was using told me to select Run script when only installing inside the build phases in the project to run a script. I couldn't find this and the closest thing worded as so was "for install builds only", which I selected.
